# Matlab label names won't work when decimals are in the names

Tags: matlab, label

I am trying to set the y axis to have ticks every 0.25 points from 0-4 and have labels on those ticks on 0,0.5,1,1.5,...

This code works when I do not have any decimal points in my numbers but fails with error once I add in 0.5 and 1.5 etc.

```
set(gca,'YTick',(0:.25:4), 'FontSize', 13)
set(gca,'YTickLabel',['0';' ';'0.5';' ';'1';' ';'1.5';' ';'2';' ';'2.5';' ';'3';' ';'3.5';' ';'4'])
```

This is the matlab error message:

```
Error using generateWiresharkTracePlot (line 63)
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Does anyone have an idea for a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**
You are building a 2D `char` matrix using

```
['0';' ';'0.5';' ';'1';' ';'1.5';' ';'2';' ';'2.5';' ';'3';' ';'3.5';' ';'4']
```

You are trying to define rows with 1 char (e.g., `'0'`) and rows with 3 chars (e.g., `'1.5'`).

**Solution 1:**

Convert all rows to thress chars:

```
[' 0 ';'   ';'0.5';'   ';' 1 ';' ';'1.5';'   ';' 2 ';'   ';'2.5';'   ';' 3 ';'   ';'3.5';' ';' 4 ']
```

**Solution 2:**

Use cell array instead of 2D char matrix (Note the curly braces):

```
{'0';' ';'0.5';' ';'1';' ';'1.5';' ';'2';' ';'2.5';' ';'3';' ';'3.5';' ';'4'}
```

This solution is better in terms of generalization and good practice.